# Is there a fully managed (.NET) Lua interpreter?

Tags: c#, silverlight, lua, aluminumlua

Does anyone know if there is a fully managed (.NET) Lua interpreter?  The regular source can be compiled with managed extensions for desktop .NET, but it can't be embedded in a Silverlight application.

Answer (score 10):

There another project called [Lua.Net](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/luanet/)

Check [Aluminum Lua](https://github.com/chkn/AluminumLua), It is completely written in C#.

Comment: As I understand it is just a interface to the Lua interpreter not a (pure) reimplementation in .NET. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @ba__friend, at least Aluminum Lua is purely on .NET, which has no dependency on any external Lua interpreter. But not sure if it supports Silverlight (SL has too many things ripped).

Comment: The Lua.net link is dead now. The author calls Aluminum Lua a "toy project," and says it's not maintained.

Answer (score 5):

I have written a Lua interpreter for .NET

It's a complete rewrite, it uses Irony for parsing and supports most of Lua 5.2 features, even if it lacks debug functions. Also only basic functions are provided, but custom ones can be easily written.
http://github.com/frabert/NetLua

Answer (score 3):

I did a complete line-for-line port of Lua 5.1.4 to C# including the libraries and tools, it's been used successfully with Unity and partially with XNA (minus the bits that need reflection):

http://www.ppl-pilot.com/kopilua.aspx

You might wanna check GitHub though, I believe it's been forked and updated by others since (although I'm not sure if they went to the same lengths I did to make sure it was a 100% faithful port).

Comment: Since originally writing this I've also starting hosting the package on both [github](https://github.com/Myndale/KopiLua) and [NuGet](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/KopiLua).